# Escalar sitio en Azure

Tags: azure

Esta pregunta esta basada en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5069/como-balancear-tr%C3%A1fico?answertab=active#tab-top

Básicamente me gustaría saber como escalar mi sitio web cuando tenga muchas peticiones, puesto que esta teniendo mucho éxito.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

creo que esta publicación te puede servir:

http://www.slideshare.net/zemoreno1/como-crear-un-balanceador-de-carga-58947336

Revisala :)

Cuando tienes un sitio web publicado en Microsoft Azure puedes hacer uso del servicio Traffic Manager. Que te permite balancear cargar de tráfico desde distintos regiones del mundo. De tal manera que cierto tráfico puede apuntar a "America" y otro hacia "Europa" por así decirlo. Entonces tu tráfico se segmenta y existe menos carga a tu sitio web, por lo que tiene una probailidad inferior a caerse. El ejemplo práctico viene en el documento de SlideShare.

Comment: Lo que presentas acá es un comentario, no una respuesta. Una respuesta debe ser auto suficiente en el sentido de que provee la información necesaria para responder a la pregunta en cuestión. Los enlaces a sitios externos sirven para complementar la información de la respuesta. Una respuesta no puede ser solo un enlace.

Comment: en que diapositiva se menciona como escalar el sitio ?

Comment: Por favor, añade en tu respuesta un resumen de la información proporcionada en el enlace. Si no, esta respuesta debería ser más bien un comentario.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando configuras un `web app` puede definir los criterios con los cuales debe escalar

Dentro del Portal de Azure usarias la opcion `All settings` y luego `Scale Up`

Aqui deberias tener en cuenta segun el plan que tengas si seleccionar un modo `Shared` o `Basic`

Recuerda que el precio por el servicio se incrementara si escalas el sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este artículo

[Scale a web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/)

se explica con mayor detalle

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que menciona Leandro, en tu escenario donde recibes muchas peticiones, la variable sobre la cual te recomiendo basar tu lógica de escalado es el Http Queue Length, que es básicamente la cantidad de peticiones que están esperando ser atendidas, de esta forma, si tienes muchas en espera, escalas para atenderlas y cuando el tráfico se estabiliza, puedes bajar.